# Java MP3 player - play, pause & seek not working as intended with jLayer

Tags: java, mp3

I'm trying to implement mp3 player in java that will play audio from array of bytes.

The class should work like this:

1. Load mp3 file encrypted with aes
2. Decrypt it to array of bytes / inputstream
3. Play the music from variable
4. Let user pause/stop/rewind it

The point is that my implementation using jLayer is not working: when I do play - pause - resume, the audio is being paused but then resumed from random point in file.

```
public class MPlayer{
    AdvancedPlayer player;
    private static int pausedOnFrame =0;
    private byte[] decrypted = null;
    private long audioLength;
    private AudioInputStream stream;
    private InputStream bytesToStream(byte[] in) {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(in);
        return is;
    }

    public MPlayer(String fname) {
        /* here file is encrypted to variable byte[] decrypted and then: */
        InputStream is = bytesToStream(decrypted);
        stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);
        audioLength = stream.getFrameLength();

        player = new AdvancedPlayer(stream);
        player.setPlayBackListener(new PlaybackListener() {
            @Override
            public void playbackFinished(PlaybackEvent event) {
                System.err.println(event.getFrame());
                pausedOnFrame = event.getFrame();
            }

        }
    }

    public void play() throws Exception {
        Thread th = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                player.play(MPlayer.pausedOnFrame, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            }
        };
        th.start();
    }

    public void fastforward() {
        pausemusic();
        long nextFrame = (long) (pausedOnFrame+0.02*audioLength);
        if (nextFrame < audioLength)
            play();
    }
    public void rewind() {
        pausemusic();
        long nextFrame = (long) (pausedOnFrame-0.02*audioLength);
        if (nextFrame > 0)
            play();
        }
    }

    public void pausemusic() throws LineUnavailableException {
        player.stop();
    }
    public void stopmusic() throws LineUnavailableException {
        player.stop();
        pausedOnFrame = 0;
    }
}
```

How may I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have to be calling stop on your pause method and not giving it a location.

```
    public void pausemusic() throws LineUnavailableException {
    player.stop();
}
public void stopmusic() throws LineUnavailableException {
    player.stop();
    pausedOnFrame = 0;
}
```

I'm not familiar with how your code works, but if the 'stopmusic' method resets the song to 0 via the 'pausedOnFrame = 0', why don't you keep a counter during the play so that you can create a pause method that knows where to locate itself?

In short, why aren't you tracking where the song is?

Comment: Notice what's happening in PlaybackListener